# Compare dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to check if 2 dates are equal in a sql script?

The value passed from front end is '2010-12-04 22:14:49' and the date in the table is '2010-12-04 22:14:49.253'

I don't care about the millisec. I tried this

```
DATEDIFF(SS,'2010-12-04 22:14:49','2010-12-04 22:14:49.253') = 0
```

and got the following error

> The datediff function resulted in an
>   overflow. The number of dateparts
>   separating two date/time instances is
>   too large. Try to use datediff with a
>   less precise datepart.

Comment: I don't get that error with your sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my SQL Server (2008 R2) this snippet of T-SQL code works just fine....

Are you sure you didn't introduce a typo (e.g. `1010-12-04......`) in your dates somehow, so that the distance between the two dates would be really really large??

Then the number of seconds between them could indeed overflow even SQL Server's large numeric range - and that's exactly what the error message is saying...

Comment: Thanks there was a typo.There is a chance a user  will try to search for dates with a longer gap. In that case how do I prevent this error?

Comment: @Dotnetrocks: maybe you should check for DATEDIFF with e.g. DAY first - if it's less than a DAY in difference, then you can check with SECONDS. Or just catch the exception - if it happens, the dates are obviously quite a bit apart.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using this in a `WHERE` clause against a `datetime` column?

If so just use

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '2010-12-04 22:14:49.000'

SELECT ....
WHERE YourCol >= @d AND YourCol < DATEADD(SECOND,1,@d)
```

This will be more sargable and efficient anyway.

Comment: is there a way to remove the seconds from the date. Then I can do a one on one comparison

Comment: Probably. If you apply a function to the column to remove the seconds you are guaranteeing that an index cannot be used to satisfy this query though and you will scan the whole table. My query as written can be satisfied with a range seek.

Comment: @dotnetrocks You can remove milliseconds from your param with SET @d = DATEADD(MS, -DATEPART(MS, @d), @d)

Answer (score 0):

This removes the seconds from the dates

```
where convert (varchar(10), @date1, 108) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), @date1, 108) = convert (varchar(10), @date2, 108) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), @date2, 108)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast each of the datetime values like the example below:

```
declare @stuff as datetime
set @stuff = getdate()
select @stuff
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), @stuff, 120)
```

Output =

```
2010-12-05 16:17:49.720
```

and

```
2010-12-05 16:17:49
```

Conversion to type 120 does not include milliseconds.

Follow this [LINK](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) for other types of conversions.